# Is there any formula for automatic "price to bar ratio" calculation?

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a script that calculates the angle of the trend and for the calculations to coincide with my chart, I use the same "Lock price to bar ratio" setting for the chart and the script.
The problem is that each asset has a different price and for correct angle calculations, I need to manually change this setting for each asset. However, if you disable this setting and enable auto scaling,
TradingView will automatically calculate the optimal *price to bar ratio* for the chart. Is there any formula for automatic calculation of this *price to bar ratio* or other solutions to the problem?

"Lock price to bar ratio" button:

[image: "Lock price to bar ratio" button]

Comment: This ration is not accessible in Pine Script, but if you want to calculate angles, you might want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650047/angle-of-line-in-pine-script)

Comment: @BjornMistiaen I calculate angles successfully. But if I want to apply the script to assets with different prices, the same "price to bar ratio" may not work and the angles will be calculated incorrectly.