# Get the Price to Bar Ratio

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Returning to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374118/is-there-any-formula-for-automatic-price-to-bar-ratio-calculation), is it still impossible to obtain ***"***price to bar ratio***"*** with the new version of pinescript?

Comment: afaik the price to bar ratio is still not available through Pine Script.