# How to draw lines and check the degrees between certain highs and lows

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hello I have this simple code that tells me the where are the lows and highs

```
pHigh = (high[1] > high[2]) and (high <= high[1] )
pLow = (low[1] < low[2]) and (low >= low[1] )
plotshape(pHigh, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, offset = -1)
plotshape(pLow, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, offset = -1)
```

Can you please let me know how can I do this:

For each pLow I want to consider the pHighs and pLows in front of it and compute the degree, then if the degrees are equal 50 I draw lines.

eg. lets say there is a plow at `bar_index[100]`, then I want to compute the degree between the the highest phigh between 1) the `plow[100]` and `phigh[i]` (100>i>=0) and 2) lowest low between the `phigh[100]` and
plows[k] (k<i and k<100 and it is moving forward basically).

If the degree between the lines for every three points (`plow[100]`, `phigh[i]`, `plow[k]`) are 50 I want to draw a line like what I showed in the fig.

As we move ahead, the highest high between the plow and `phigh[i]` and lowest low between the `phigh[i]` and `plows` (from i forward , ie plow[k]) should be considered for checking the degree.

when computing the degrees we only draw lines if the degree is equal to 50. otherwise we ignore.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you wanted to do, so I'm not writing this as an answer, but if you're looking to get the angle (degree) of a line you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650047/angle-of-line-in-pine-script). Keep in mind that since v5, the `atan` function has been changed to `math.atan`

Answer (score 2):

consider pHighs and pLows before them as follows:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
fHigh(hi) =>
    pHigh = (hi[1] > hi[2]) and (hi <= hi[1])
fLow(lo) =>
    pLow = (lo[1] < lo[2]) and (lo >= lo[1])

plotshape(fHigh(high), style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, offset = -1, color = color.red)
plotshape(fLow(low), style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, offset = -1)


bool pLowHigh = na
bool pLowLow = na
if fLow(low)
    pLowLow := fLow(low[1])
if fHigh(high)
    pLowHigh:= fHigh(high[1])
```

But with this definition pHigh and pLow it is not possible to calculate the degree and make further calculations, because they series bool.

You need to change the initial calculation pHigh and pLow, for they return series float

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think this is a good hint, I will try to use it and  progress on  the top of it and update the question. Thank you!